# Keyboard handling on a UIModalPresentationFormSheet presented sheet

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have a UIViewController that is presented with UIModalPresentationFormSheet. So when the keyboard is visible it stays visible until the view controller gets dismissed.

In that UIViewController I have a navigation controller. So in every UIViewController pushed to that navigation controller I have to check these things:

- when the keyboard shows/hides I have to adjust the contentInset
- when view appears I have to check if the keyboard is visible or not (the navigation controller remembers that with the notification) and adjust the contentInset. I push UITableViewControllers there, so I don't get viewDidAppear and co. So I have to do all this with the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods?
- on every rotation I have to do adjust the contentInset

Otherwise the keyboard may cover some content.

Is that the correct handling? Isn't there any easier solution for this problem? Because this is kind a messy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a better solution, so i did it this way.